# Binomial Probability (Dice)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice, binomial-theorem

The throwing of a one or two is called a success. The six dice are thrown together 64 times and the frequencies of the throws with 0, 1, 2,..., 6 successes are summed over all six pairs are as follows:

Success:      0    1    2    3     4    5   6 
Frequency:    0    4   19    15   17    7   2

(a)What would be the theoretical probability of success and the mean and variance of the above frequency distribution is all the dice were fair?

My friend and I got different answers. I multiplied by the successes from 0,..6, and my friend multiplied by the frequencies.

Who is correct?

[image]
[image]

(c) Test the hypothesis that the mean and variance have their theoretical mean? 
 
What kind of test would you suggest? 2-sample binomial test and we can approx with Z? And what kind of test for variance? Chi-sqaured?

Thanks!

Comment: The theoretical distribution is binomial with rate of success $1/3$ and number of trials $6$. It is usually denoted by $\text{Binomial}(1/3, 6)$. The mean is $2$ and the variance is $ 4/3$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution is the second one, so you are correct. Part (a) of the problem should not have anything to do with the empirical frequencies.

For Part (c), Chi-squared test seems appropriate.